# Reset Active Directory Passwords Using RHEL6

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, redhat, ubuntu-10.04

Does anyone know of a way to reset Active Directory Passwords through RHEL6 or Ubuntu 10.04LTS so that the Active Directory user can still access network resources with their AD account. Also, is there a way to implement a policy where users receive a reminder when their password is about to expire?

Comment: Is your linux box connected to your AD?

Comment: Are just you trying to allow somebody who uses a Linux box to reset their AD password? It is possible to configure IIS to give users a web page where they can reset their password, that might be worth some research.